# Woocommerce order due date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use WooCommerce to sell a design service which is phased (draft, approval, customer review, phase 2, final delivery...). I'm using Order Status Manager to have custom status and email customer on each status update. I need to set up a DUE DATE for each phase of each order.

Basically the result would be:

```
Order: #100 - Status: Pending Payment Confirmation - Due Date: None
Order: #100 - Status: Send initial draft - Due Date: June 22, 2018
Order: #100 - Status: Send review - Due Date: June 24, 2018
Order: #100 - Status: Send final version - Due Date: June 26, 2018
```

Basically: setting up the dates myself in a new custom column on WooCommerce order page.

Those date should not be visible to customers. The deadlines are our own control.

[Here's the image of what the result should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0W9m.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want two things.

1. Add the custom field 'Due date' to each order.
2. On order status change, set the Due date accordingly.

---

UPDATE, OP changed question.

Creating a custom column to display custom order meta data is fairly straightforward. If you want to set (save) data directly in the column you have to decide how to do this, IMHO Ajax is the best solution.

In short the code below does the following:

- Create custom due date column on wc orders page.
- Populate custom column with input.
- Handle wp ajax call server side.
- Load JS footer script that sets datepicker and saves new due date
  with Ajax.

Place this code in your **child**-theme `functions.php`. Use a child theme, so you can still update your theme!

Tested with WOO 3.4.2

Please see the code comments for further information.

```
/**
 * Load jQuery datepicker on WC orders page
**/
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_orders_page_enqueue_datepicker' );
function wc_orders_page_enqueue_datepicker() {
  global $pagenow;
  if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
  }
}

/**
 * Add due date column to WC orders page before the order_total column
**/
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wc_due_date_order_column' );
function wc_due_date_order_column( $columns ) {
  $new_columns = array();
  foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
    if ( $column_name == 'order_total' ) {
      $new_columns['order_due_date'] = 'Due Date';
    }
    $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;
  }
  return $new_columns;
}

/**
 * Set due date column content
**/
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wc_due_date_column_content' );
function wc_due_date_column_content( $column ) {
  global $post;
  if ( $column == 'order_due_date' ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    $due_date = $order->get_meta( '_order_due_date', true );
    error_log('due date: '.$due_date);

    // a tag is needed to break default wc 'go to order on tr click' behaviour
    echo '<a id="'.$post->ID.'" href="#"><input type="text" class="order_due_date" name="order_due_date" style="width:65%" value="'.$due_date.'"/><div class="ajax_due_date_notice" style="display:inline-block; width:32%; margin-left:2%;"></div></a>';
  }
}

/**
 * Handle save due date ajax call
**/
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_due_date', 'ajax_save_due_date' );
function ajax_save_due_date() {
  check_ajax_referer( 'dgfdgDFSKF32', 'security' ); // if check failed, this method will run wp_die()
  $order_id = intval( $_POST['order_id'] );
  $new_due_date = $_POST['new_due_date'];

  if($order_id && $new_due_date) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if($order) {
      $order->update_meta_data( '_order_due_date', $new_due_date );
      $order->save();
      echo '1';
    } else {
      echo '0';
    }
  } else {
    echo '0';
  }
  wp_die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}

/**
 * Admin footer script that sets the datepicker and handles due date input changes
**/
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wc_due_date_footer_script' );
function wc_due_date_footer_script() {
  global $pagenow;
  $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "dgfdgDFSKF32" );

  if (( $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) && ($_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order')) :
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('.order_due_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
      });

      $( "input[name='order_due_date']" ).change(function() {
        var order_id = $(this).closest('a').attr('id');
        var new_due_date = $(this).val();
        var ajax_notice = $(this).closest('a').find('.ajax_due_date_notice');
        if(order_id && new_due_date) {
          ajax_notice.html('Saving...');
          ajax_save_order_due_date(order_id, new_due_date);
        }
      });

      // save due date with ajax
      var ajax_save_order_due_date = function(order_id, new_due_date) {
        var data = {
          action: 'save_due_date',
          security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
          order_id: order_id,
          new_due_date: new_due_date
        };
        $.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
          console.log('response: ',response);
          if(response === '1') {
            $('a#'+order_id).find('.ajax_due_date_notice').html('<span style="color:green;">Saved!</span>');
            setTimeout(function(){ $('a#'+order_id).find('.ajax_due_date_notice').html(''); }, 3000);
          } else {
            $('a#'+order_id).find('.ajax_due_date_notice').html('<span style="color:red;">Saving failed!</span>');
          }
        });
      }

    });
  </script>
  <?php
  endif;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. I'm not looking for someone to develop a free plug-in, just asked if there was any that could do that or a manual alternative. Sorry if I caused some misunderstanding. =) So let me simplify the request: Any way to insert a datepicker option column in the WooCommerce Order Page (where it lists each order)? Thank you!

Comment: I have simplified the request and added an image to represent the expected result. Again, thank you!

Comment: I had some free time, so I created a working solution for you, see my updated answer. As you can see, you cannot accomplish this with a few lines of code, that's why I mentioned the 'free plugin'.